# Magento 2: How to change the position/order of a sub-category?

Tags: magento2, category

I'm trying to change sub category order into magento 2. Look at the image below:

[image]

I tried it from dashboard, I change position using drag and drop features. But it is not appear in same sequence into the front-end page.

[image]

I flush cache and did reindex too. But still no changes appear into the front-end page. Can anyone help me.

Thanks,
Omar

Comment: Share your code that you are using to show subcategories